# Assert Fails even though actual and expected match

Tags: c#, selenium, assert, specflow

My code is as below -

```
string Nodata = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='gridView_EMPLOYEE_DXEmptyRow']/td[1]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");

Assert.AreEqual("No data to display", Nodata.Trim());
```

Assert fails with message-

```
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<No data to display>. Actual:<<div>
                No data to display
            </div>>.
```

[image: See the screenshot below]

Comment: The message is correct; the Actual and Expected in your screen shot do not match.

Comment: @Seema, please check [ask question in a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Dour High Arch , The screenshots are from the Visual studio where it says the expected and actual do not match . How do i get rid of the <<div>> from the actual ??

Comment: Nodata.Trim() returns <<div> No data to display <<div> . How do I remove that from both sides to just compare the text "No data to display"

Comment: use regex to get rid of <div> tags.

Comment: oh boy...please tell me how does `<No data to display>` and  `<div>No data to display</div>`  match?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jPhizzle, we all have said the same.

Comment: @its4zahoor ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to check with `<div>` tags (Be Careful about spaces)

```
  Assert.AreEqual("<div>No data to display</div>", Nodata.Trim());
```